# sqlsrv_connect not connecting on WAMP but will connect on IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, sqlsrv

I have a website in development on IIS but i'm moving to a new laptop and decided to use WAMP instead.

I have installed the correct version of the driver of sqlsrv for PHP as it shows up in phpinfo as enabled.

However it won't connect to the database, it's an exact copy of my working directory but in WAMP rather than IIS.

This is the code below just from a connection test file and it fails every time.

**CODE**

```
<?php
$serverName = "OMITTED";
$connectionInfo = array ("Database"=>"OMITTED", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>'OMITTED');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === FALSE){
    die("Failed to connect to database!");
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: What is the error you get when it fails to connect? Also, your website should *not* be using the `sa` `LOGIN` to access your SQL Server instance.

Comment: Yes I know, as I said this is just the test environment, the live website is different. The error is there, 'Failed to connect to database'.

Comment: That isn't the error, that's your message in your code: `die("Failed to connect to database!");` We need to error, please.

Comment: The client side errors are almost meaningless, so as to avoid helping hackers. Check the SQL Server's ERRORLOG file for Error 18456 messages and compare the State number there against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error).

Comment: There's nothing regarding this connection in the error logs, so it looks like it's not even attempting the connection.

Comment: Try `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` instead of your current one so you at least have some hints to progress on. Potentially use a port number in your `$serverName = "yourServerNameOrIpAddress,portNumber";` as well to avoid SQL Browser service issues.

Comment: 'The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted', I've added the cacert and updated the php.ini files but still no luck.

Comment: SQL Server installations use self-signed certificates by default. This is probably not the same certificate used by IIS. Unless you've somehow gotten a CA-signed certificate for it (such as from an internal organizational CA) you'll either need to use `TrustServerCertificate=true;` to blindly accept the cert, or `Encrypt=false;` to use unencrypted connections, or get the public key portion of the certificate from the SQL Server instance to add to your trusted certificates store on the WAMP machine.